# Implementing Linear regression with leave-one-out cross validation in MATLAB

Tags: regression, matlab

I have a data set of 87 variables and 1 outcome where all are continuous. I need to use linear regression with leave-one-out cross validation to create a model/equation with prediction's accuracy, sensitivity, and specificity.

- Can I use Regression Learner app for this? If yes how to get quation from a created model in Regression Learner app?
- Can/Should I use cross validation to divide my data set and get the results?
- Is there any code sample on how to go about doing this? (I'm new to all of this)
- Should I be using `stepwiselm` or `fitlm` or `glmfit/glmval`? What's the difference and how do I choose?

Comment: What is Regression Learner app?

Comment: It's a builtin app in MATLAB for regression analysis. https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/regression-learner-app.html